# Valence and Quiz Tool

Tags: desire2learn, valence

Are there any undocumented API calls that would allow for any basic read only retrieval of quiz information within a course?  We are really just trying to get number of quizzes in a course, whether it's TurnItIn enabled, etc.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no *Valence* APIs for Quiz tools. However D2L/Brightspace does expose quizzes through its legacy SOAP API. Which is how products such as [Respondus](https://www.respondus.com/products/respondus/index.shtml) work.
There is an SDK here: https://github.com/Brightspace/d2lws-sdk

Comment: Keep in mind that D2LWS (the SOAP service) is explicitly deprecated; it may still be present in your back-end Brightspace instance, but you won't get any priority in support or assistance with it; it is still supported in an "out of maintenance" deprecated fashion though, and it likely won't go completely away any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Brightspace does not support any APIs for public use around quiz collections or quiz items.

Comment: Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Currently, it's simply a matter of business priority.